# How to add custom text in front of price in the cart page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I want to add some custom text in front of the price in the Magento cart page as shown in the image.

I found the following  lines in the `app\design\frontend\mydesign\default\template\checkout\cart.phtml`

There is following code

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
      <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
 <?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
```

But how to edit this and in which file I am not getting.
Please help.
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Change the currency?

Comment: @Reindex'EmAll I have two stores in my site Australia and USA based on the store I want to place USD or AUD before the price.

Comment: This is really not a way to do it. I suggest you do some research on managing currencies in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->getItemHtml($_item)` actually loads the template file `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml`. So just copy it from `base` theme folder to your theme folder and modify it. The text "AUD" can be added to the `<td>` cell that displays the product price.

If you want to add "AUD" everywhere a price is displayed, you can go to admin and change currency symbols under `System -> Manage Currency -> Symbols`

Answer (score 0):

when you are beginner of magento and active theme package is "rwd"
than you find product details of "<'tbody'>" on shopping cart page is below path:
C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml